# Applied Mathematics problems

Tags: problem-solving

Does anyone know where one would be able to find real world mathematics problems?

For example, given the weight of a satellite and the performance of a rocket, develop a simple mission plan to deliver the cargo to geostationary orbit.

I am interested in applying what I am learning in college to some more complex and involved problems.

Comment: What level are you at right now in maths?

Comment: Just completed calculus 1 final today.

Comment: You'll likely want to pick up at least multivariable calculus in order to even formulate such problems, and probably differential equations if you want to get analytical solutions to them (when that is possible, which it usually isn't).

Comment: Thanks, im starting calc 2 soon and then right after that calc 3, I was just wondering if anyone knew of any resources. All I can find are the standard text book questions.

Comment: Why don't you try grabbing a book in introductory physics? Many of these concepts are explorable with just one-variable calculus, and the combined physical intuition and mathematical sophistication required of a reader might be enough complexity, while staying at your level.

Answer (score 0):

[The Brachistochrone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cld0p3a43fU) by 3Blue1Brown might be a good place to start. In general you might find a book on differential geometry interesting, e.g. Millman & Parker or Do Carmo.

Comment: While I agree with the spirit of this answer, OP is probably not ready for differential geometry, since they do not have any knowledge of multivariate or vector calculus.

Comment: An introductory physics book probably uses line integrals etc extensively, which I could make sense of only after taking differential geometry, though we're probably suggesting more or less the same thing.